# Goblin Army doesn't spawn after using the Battle Standard

Tags: xbox-360, terraria-console

The goblin army didn't spawn when I used goblin battle standard item. It consumed the item, but no goblins spawned. I haven't collected enough tattered cloth to try again yet.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible to summon the Goblin Army using the battle stand, although there are a few notes that should be taken:

- A Goblin Army (and all later invasions) spawn around the center of the map, with the exception of the first wave, which will come from east or west. This will be announced through the message : "A Goblin army is approaching from the east/west!".
- After the first wave reaches the center of the map, all future waves will spawn around the center of the map.
- The amount of Goblins that will spawn is 80+40 for each player in the world.
- You cannot summon a Goblin Invasion if:

  - You have less than 200 health.
  - You haven't smashed any Shadow Orbs/Crimson hearts yet.
  - If there is another invasion going on.

Answer (score 0):

It only works at the place you first spawned and if you didn't use it at the spawn just go there and they should appear

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you still need help but if you do you need a minimum of 200 health I had this problem as well. So just mine near the dungeon and you should find some crystal hearts.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is very common among many gamers, it is very easy to solve though. They spawn near or directly on top of your original or new spawn point, they also will spawn on top of your town and try to get rid of your NPCs in the progress.